# Error accessing with JDBC two (SQLite) tables that are in separate databases

Tags: database, sqlite, jdbc

I need to copy data from one table of a SQLite DB (in this case unsc1.unsc) to another new table of another DB ( CompleteNewDB.new_table), **via JDBC**. I keep getting the error: "SQL error or missing database (no such table: unsc).

The tables exist; the sqlite query works as I've tried it separately using another software. Is there a mistake in the procedure and the way i tried implementing it?  Is there an easier way to copy data with JDBC from table1 to table2, each respectively being in separate databases?

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection un1 = null;
    Connection un2 = null;
    Connection newDB = null;

    Statement stmt1 = null;
    Statement stmt2 = null;

    String queryCreate = "CREATE TABLE newtable ("
            + "m_code_txt TEXT, "
            + "m_date_txt TEXT, "
            + "m_filename TEXT, "
            + "m_resumption_int INT, "
            + "m_status_txt TEXT, "
            + "m_suspension_int INT, "
            + "m_agenda_txt TEXT, "
            + "p_name_txt TEXT, "
            + "p_nation_txt TEXT, "
            + "p_role_txt TEXT, "
            + "s_speech_lang TEXT, "
            + "s_speech_txt TEXT, "
            + "s_speech_pos REAL );";

    String queryData = "INSERT INTO new_table "
            + "SELECT * "
            + "FROM unsc1.unsc;";


    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        //DB unsc1
        un1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:unsc1.db");
        System.out.println("Connection to unsc1.db established");

        //DB unsc2
        un2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:unsc2.db");
        System.out.println("Connection to unsc2.db established");


        //Migrated DB           
        newDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:CompleteNewDB.db");
        System.out.println("Creation & Connection to CompleteNewDB.db established");


        //First query: create a table in new database 
        stmt1 = newDB.createStatement();
        stmt1.execute(queryCreate);
        System.out.println("Created table in CompleteNewDB ");
        stmt1.close();


        //PROBLEM HERE: copy data from table in database "unsc1.db" to the new_table ??
        stmt2 = newDB.createStatement();
        stmt2.execute(queryData);
        System.out.println("Copied data from first DB to new DB.");
        stmt2.close();

        //closing all
        un1.close();
        un2.close();
        newDB.close(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To access multiple  databases in one SQL (as with `queryData` above), subordinate databases need to be [`ATTACH`ed](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html). I am not familiar with jdbc, so I cannot give specific guidance on how to accomplish that.

Another option, of course, would be to select the rows from the first database into some program data structure, then perform INSERT(s) into second database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `ATTACH` command may be what I really need! I'm already using your second option, which works, but the copying time is **really** slow